# std::transform on temporary object

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a function returning a vector of objects, and I want to create a vector of members taken from these objects. I am using std::transform to do this. However, the code segfualts. GDB wasn't very helpful. Could anyone explain what is happening?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Container
{
    private:
    string _id;

    public:
    Container(const string &str): _id(str) {}

    const decltype(_id) &id() const {
        return this->_id;
    }

};

Container a{"hello"}, b{"world"};

vector<Container *> fn()
{
    return {&a,&b};
}

int main() {
    vector<string> ids;
    const auto &elements = fn();
    std::transform(elements.begin(), elements.end(), ids.begin(), [](const Container *container){ return container->id();});

}
```

Comment: `elements` Points to an expired temporary

Comment: That's actually okay. The life of the temporary is extended by the const reference. I should've used the back inserter to ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ids.begin()` is not an iterator into a valid range of length `elements.size()`, since `ids` is empty and `elements` has size 2.

You probably want `std::back_inserter(ids)` instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> ids;

std::transform(elements.begin(), elements.end(),
               std::back_inserter(ids),
               [](const Container *container){ return container->id();});

assert(ids.size() == elements.size());
```

Comment: When looking at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform, I am trying to find a hint to the fact that the output iterator must point to the beginning of a valid range of sufficient size, but I cannot find it. The `back_inserter` example is there as well, but no explicit requirement on the output iterator. Is this obvious to everyone else or just missing info in the doc?

Comment: Well, the effects are described as "stores the result in another range, beginning at d_first" (the actual [standards wording](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.transform#3) is similar), so you can infer from that that the destination of the assignment must exist. I think this is covered by blanket wording somewhere that arguments must be valid for their intended use.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<string> ids;` is an empty vector and you are trying to add elements to it using a normal iterator.  This is going to cause a segfault as you are going to access memory you do not own.  What you need is a [`back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to `push_back` the elements into the vector.

```
std::transform(elements.begin(), elements.end(), std::back_inserter(ids),
               [](const Container *container){ return container->id();});
```